# Unable to delete LWC and Apex Classes from Production Org: Entity is Deleted

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, deployment

We created a Lightning Web Component, which has an Apex Controller and Test class. The component is no longer needed and we now want to try and delete it. Using my IDE (IntelliJ and Illuminated Cloud) we deleted the LWC. When trying to delete the classes however, we received an error noting that the controller class is still referenced by the LWC.

The LWC is still visible in Setup -> Lighting Components -> Lightning Components, or through the Tooling API. However, it is not visible in the Recycle Bin.

When trying to delete the LWC, the controller and test class, or all, we receive errors. Below screenshot shows the errors for deleting the LWC (1), the controller and test class (2) and all three items (3).
[image: Errors when removing LWC - Entity is Deleted]

How do we break this Catch22 situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was in contact with Salesforce Support, and in the end they had someone "clear some blocking data" so they could remove the component. There was nothing we could have done to do it ourselves. That's all I know...

Answer (score 2):

May be you can achieve your goal with destructiveChanges.xml and [Workbanch](https://workbench.developerforce.com/)

Here is an example for apex class, but it should work for lwc components as well.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000BioCQAS

Comment: Unfortunatly this gives me the same response: Entity Is Deleted...